# Problem converting from Java ArrayList http response to a javaobj Python object/list

Tags: java, python-3.x, arraylist, httpresponse

My python program connect to a web service that returns a Java ArrayList (of a custom classtype called ObjectListEntry, which contains 6 attributes). I am having trouble constructing a Python list using javaobj from the returned stream. I have tried with both v1 and v2 and get different exceptions.

Windows 10, Eclipse 2019-12, PyDev 7.5
Python 3.8.1
javaobj-py3, installed via pip (0.4.0.1?)

I am performing the following steps (code as well as exception trace below)

1. Retrieve the response
2. Check status code
3. Convert the response.text string to a bytestream (from UTF-8, the default Python string encoding)
4. Print the bytearray (parts are recognizable as the data I want :-) )
5. Pass the byte array to javaobj.loads function, which throws the exception...

I am wondering whether the program fails because it receives data belonging to a custom class. How would I provide this class definition or its Python equivalent to javaobj? It seems like there is a fairly obvious step that I am missing and would like your help. Thanks for the replies!

**Update:** I saw this code about adding custom tansformers on the release as well as GitHub pages *[javaobj GitHub page](https://github.com/tcalmant/python-javaobj) and added my custom transformer in the v2 loads call... to no effect

```
# import javaobj
import javaobj.v2 as javaobj

# later, in a method
        response = requests.post( f'https://{self.fedora_server}{self.fedora_path}getObjectList',
                                  headers=headers, params=params)
        print("Response status: ", response.status_code) # displays 200

        data = bytearray( response.text, encoding='UTF-8')
        print("data from server is: ", data) # displays partially recognizable byte string

        pobj = javaobj.loads( data) # all hell breaks loose :-| --initial post
        pobj = javaobj.loads( data, Cm4fObjListEntryTransformer()) # all hell breaks loose :-| --after update

        print (pobj)
```

The exception trace with javaobj.v1

```
Response status:  200
data from server is:  bytearray(b'\xc2\xac\xc3\xad\x00\x05sr\x00%org.emile.cm4f.models.ObjectListEntry\xe2\x80\xa1\x04\xe2\x80\xba\xe2\x80\x9e6\xc2\xb6\xc2\xb8\x18\x02\x00\x06L\x00\x0ccontentModelt\x00\x12Ljava/lang/String;L\x00\x06handleq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\nlastUpdateq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x05ownerq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x03pidq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x05titleq\x00~\x00\x01xpt\x00\x13http://cm4f.org/TEIt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1001t\x00\x182020-02-17T14:39:55.933Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0bo:emile.teit\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x13http://cm4f.org/PDFt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1006t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.101Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0bo:emile.pdft\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x18http://cm4f.org/Resourcet\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1008t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.261Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x10o:emile.resourcet\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x15http://cm4f.org/Storyt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1010t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.381Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\ro:emile.storyt\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x14http://cm4f.org/SKOSt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1009t\x00\x182020-02-17T14:39:56.769Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0co:emile.skost\x00\x0bTest Object')
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-redacted\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "path-redacted\dlgfcrepoconnect.py", line 156, in _connect_btn_clicked
    my_fed_con.stub_get_object_list(username, "filter(regex(str(?pid), '^o:'))", 5)
  File "path-redacted\fedoraapi\fedoraconnection.py", line 65, in stub_get_object_list
    pobj = javaobj.loads( data)
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v1\core.py", line 112, in loads
    return load(
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v1\core.py", line 87, in load
    marshaller = JavaObjectUnmarshaller(
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v1\unmarshaller.py", line 144, in __init__
    self._readStreamHeader()
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v1\unmarshaller.py", line 197, in _readStreamHeader
    raise IOError(
OSError: The stream is not java serialized object. Invalid stream header: C2ACC3AD
```

With javaobj.v2

```
Response status:  200
data from server is:  bytearray(b'\xc2\xac\xc3\xad\x00\x05sr\x00%org.emile.cm4f.models.ObjectListEntry\xe2\x80\xa1\x04\xe2\x80\xba\xe2\x80\x9e6\xc2\xb6\xc2\xb8\x18\x02\x00\x06L\x00\x0ccontentModelt\x00\x12Ljava/lang/String;L\x00\x06handleq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\nlastUpdateq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x05ownerq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x03pidq\x00~\x00\x01L\x00\x05titleq\x00~\x00\x01xpt\x00\x13http://cm4f.org/TEIt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1001t\x00\x182020-02-17T14:39:55.933Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0bo:emile.teit\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x13http://cm4f.org/PDFt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1006t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.101Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0bo:emile.pdft\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x18http://cm4f.org/Resourcet\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1008t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.261Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x10o:emile.resourcet\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x15http://cm4f.org/Storyt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1010t\x00\x182019-10-02T09:19:54.381Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\ro:emile.storyt\x00\x0bTest Objectsq\x00~\x00\x00t\x00\x14http://cm4f.org/SKOSt\x00\x0ehdl:11471/1009t\x00\x182020-02-17T14:39:56.769Zt\x00\x07padawant\x00\x0co:emile.skost\x00\x0bTest Object')
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path-redacted\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "path-redacted\src\gui\dlgfcrepoconnect.py", line 156, in _connect_btn_clicked
    my_fed_con.stub_get_object_list(username, "filter(regex(str(?pid), '^o:'))", 5)
  File "path-redacted\src\fedoraapi\fedoraconnection.py", line 65, in stub_get_object_list
    pobj = javaobj.loads( data)
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v2\main.py", line 82, in loads
    return load(BytesIO(data), *transformers, **kwargs)
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v2\main.py", line 57, in load
    contents = parser.run()
  File "path-redacted\lib\site-packages\javaobj\v2\core.py", line 128, in run
    raise ValueError("Invalid file magic: 0x{0:x}".format(magic))
ValueError: Invalid file magic: 0xc2ac
```

Answer (score 0):

After more, debugging, I realized that I should be using response.content, which sends the actual byte array received from the server rather than responst.text (and reconverting it to bytes).

Now I get back the number of result objects that I request. Empty objects, but still better than an exception.

Will post a separate question about custom javaobj handling.